# Arbitrary Length Hashing

Tags: code-golf, function, hashing

Consider you have a [hash function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_function) \$\mathcal{H}\$ which takes strings of length \$2n\$ and returns strings of length \$n\$ and has the nice property that it is [*collision resistant*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collision_resistance), i.e. it is hard to find two different strings \$s \neq s'\$ with the same hash \$\mathcal{H}(s) = \mathcal{H}(s')\$.

You would now like to build a new hash function \$\mathcal{H'}\$ which takes strings of **arbitrary length** and maps them to strings of length \$n\$, while still being collision resistant.

Lucky for you, already in 1979 a method now known as the [Merkle–Damgård construction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merkle%E2%80%93Damg%C3%A5rd_construction) was published which achieves exactly this.

The task of this challenge will be to implement this algorithm, so we'll first have a look at a formal description of the Merkle–Damgård construction, before going through a step-by-step example which should show that the approach is simpler than it might appear at first.

> Given some integer \$n > 0\$, a hash function \$\mathcal{H}\$ as
> described above and an input string \$s\$ of arbitrary
> length, the new hash function \$\mathcal{H'}\$ does the following:
>
> - Set \$ l = |s|\$, the length of \$s\$, and split \$s\$ in chunks of length \$n\$, filling up the last chunk with **trailing** zeros if
>   necessary. This yields \$m = \lceil \frac{l}{n} \rceil \$ many chunks
>   which are labeled \$c_1, c_2, \dots, c_m \$.
> - Add a leading and a trailing chunk \$c_0\$ and \$c_{m+1}\$, where \$c_0\$ is a string consisting of \$n\$ zeros and \$c_{m+1}\$ is \$n\$ in binary, padded with **leading** zeros to length \$n\$.
> - Now iteratively apply \$\mathcal{H}\$ to the current chunk \$c_i\$ appended to the previous result \$r_{i-1}\$: \$ r_i =
>    \mathcal{H}(r_{i-1}c_i)\$, where \$r_0 = c_0\$. *(This step might be
>   more clear after looking at the example below.)*
> - The output of \$\mathcal{H'}\$ is the final result \$r_{m+1}\$.

#### The Task

Write a program or function which takes as input a positive integer \$n\$, a hash function \$\mathcal{H}\$ as [black box](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/13706/56433) and a non-empty string \$s\$ and returns the same result as \$\mathcal{H'}\$ on the same inputs.

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the shortest answer in each language wins.

#### Example

Let's say \$n = 5\$, so our given hash function \$\mathcal{H}\$ takes strings of length 10 and returns strings of length 5.

- Given an input of \$s = \texttt{"Programming Puzzles"} \$, we get the following chunks: \$s_1 = \texttt{"Progr"} \$, \$s_2 = \texttt{"ammin"} \$, \$s_3 = \texttt{"g Puz"} \$ and \$s_4 = \texttt{"zles0"} \$. Note that \$s_4\$ needed to be padded to length 5 with one trailing zero.
- \$ c_0 = \texttt{"00000"}\$ is just a string of five zeros and \$ c_5 = \texttt{"00101"}\$ is five in binary (\$\texttt{101}\$), padded with two leading zeros.
- Now the chunks are combined with \$\mathcal{H}\$:
  \$r_0 = c_0 = \texttt{"00000"} \$
  \$ r_1 = \mathcal{H}(r_0c_1) = \mathcal{H}(\texttt{"00000Progr"})\$
  \$ r_2 = \mathcal{H}(r_1c_2) = \mathcal{H}(\mathcal{H}(\texttt{"00000Progr"})\texttt{"ammin"})\$
  \$ r_3 = \mathcal{H}(r_2c_3) = \mathcal{H}(\mathcal{H}(\mathcal{H}(\texttt{"00000Progr"})\texttt{"ammin"})\texttt{"g Puz"})\$
  \$ r_4 = \mathcal{H}(r_3c_4) = \mathcal{H}(\mathcal{H}(\mathcal{H}(\mathcal{H}(\texttt{"00000Progr"})\texttt{"ammin"})\texttt{"g Puz"})\texttt{"zles0"})\$
  \$ r_5 = \mathcal{H}(r_4c_5) = \mathcal{H}(\mathcal{H}(\mathcal{H}(\mathcal{H}(\mathcal{H}(\texttt{"00000Progr"})\texttt{"ammin"})\texttt{"g Puz"})\texttt{"zles0"})\texttt{"00101"})\$
- \$r_5\$ is our output.

Let's have a look how this output would look depending on some choices<sup>1</sup> for \$\mathcal{H}\$:

- If \$\mathcal{H}(\texttt{"0123456789"}) = \texttt{"13579"}\$, i.e. \$\mathcal{H}\$ just returns every second character, we get:
  \$r_1 = \mathcal{H}(\texttt{"00000Progr"}) = \texttt{"00Por"}\$
  \$r_2 = \mathcal{H}(\texttt{"00Porammin"}) = \texttt{"0oamn"}\$
  \$r_3 = \mathcal{H}(\texttt{"0oamng Puz"}) = \texttt{"omgPz"}\$
  \$r_4 = \mathcal{H}(\texttt{"omgPzzles0"}) = \texttt{"mPze0"}\$
  \$r_5 = \mathcal{H}(\texttt{"mPze000101"}) = \texttt{"Pe011"}\$
  So \$\texttt{"Pe011"}\$ needs to be the output if such a \$\mathcal{H}\$ is given as black box function.
- If \$\mathcal{H}\$ simply returns the first 5 chars of its input, the output of \$\mathcal{H'}\$ is \$\texttt{"00000"}\$. Similarly if \$\mathcal{H}\$ returns the last 5 chars, the output is \$\texttt{"00101"}\$.
- If \$\mathcal{H}\$ multiplies the character codes of its input and returns the first five digits of this number, e.g. \$\mathcal{H}(\texttt{"PPCG123456"}) = \texttt{"56613"}\$, then \$\mathcal{H}'(\texttt{"Programming Puzzles"}) = \texttt{"91579"}\$.

---

<sup>1 For simplicity, those \$\mathcal{H}\$ are actually not collision resistant, though this does not matter for testing your submission.</sup>

Comment: [Sandbox (deleted)](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/16650/56433)

Comment: I must say it's fun that the example given has the last 'full' hash be of "OMG Puzzles!" effectively `omgPzzles0`. Well chosen example input!

Comment: Can we assume some flexibility on the input format for H (e.g. it takes two strings of length n, or a longer string of which it only considers the first 2n characters)?

Comment: Are space characters, e.g., between "g P" valid output?

Comment: @guest271314 If the space is part of the resulting hash, it needs to be outputted. If the hash is actually "gP", you may not output a space inbetween.

Comment: @Delfad0r I'd rather say no, because *H* is a black-box function from which you only know it takes strings of a certain length and returns strings of half the length. So other assumptions like *H* ignores all but the first *n* bytes of the string should not be made.

Answer (score 7):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), <s>91</s> <s>90</s> 86 bytes

- -1 byte thanks to [Laikoni](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/56433/laikoni)
- -4 bytes thanks to [xnor](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/20260/xnor)

```hs
n!h|let a='0'<$[1..n];c?""=c;c?z=h(c++take n(z++a))?drop n z=h.(++mapM(:"1")a!!n).(a?)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fY5Ba4NAFITP8VeMSyD72K00h17aGP9AC4EejcjrZslK9EXUXKT/3a7k3sPweDPM8AUeb75tl0XS8Nv6CZzvXneHbbnPMqk@XKFU7uKZ86CdMRPfPETPxjBRcRnuPQQxy7QxHfdf@l3tFXGaCmWaC1oa6R/TiDzZlNBvFloFrWAMIUPsQJEiC3Ua7teBu66RK06PeW79qCjZ2GfnXNaWbW1/olzUJcpXeDmi5Gi6aPjqn5kqSTpuBDlWxho6Mn1Pw6esEGctFsFipHVQkCJgGz/Ck335Aw)

### Explanation

```hs
a='0'<$[1..n]
```

Just assigns the string `"00...0"` (`'0'` \$n\$ times) to `a`

---

```hs
c?""=c
c?z=h(c++take n(z++a))?drop n z
```

The function `?` implements the recursive application of `h`: `c` is the hash we have obtained so far (length \$n\$), `z` is the rest of the string. If `z` is empty then we simply return `c`, otherwise we take the first \$n\$ characters of `z` (possibly padding with zeros from `a`), prepend `c` and apply `h`. This gives the new hash, and then we call `?` recursively on this hash and the remaining characters of `z`.

---

```hs
n!h=h.(++mapM(:"1")a!!n).(a?)
```

The function `!` is the one actually solving the challenge. It takes `n`, `h` and `s` (implicit) as inputs. We compute `a?s`, and all we have to do is append `n` in binary and apply `h` once more. `mapM(:"1")a!!n` returns the binary representation of \$n\$.

Comment: `let` in a guard is shorter than using `where`: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fY7BioNAEETP8SvKIZBpZiLJYU@7xh/YQGCPKtJrhoxEO6LmIvl3dyT3PRRNV1HF8zzeXdsui8T@1boJnO4Ou69tfkwSKT/rTKm0DmdOva6NmfjuIHo2homy6/DoIQhZoo3puD/rotqf1OGoiONYKNGc0dJI/5xGpNEmh/6w0MprBWMICUIPihRZqMvwuA3cdY3ccHnOc@tGRdHGvjtFXlm2lf0NqoOuQa7E/oScg1kHw5X/zJRR1HEjSLFyVtCB6WcavmWFKLRYeIuR1kFBDI9t@Ahv9uUP "Haskell – Try It Online")

Comment: It looks like `mapM(\_->"01")a` can be `mapM(:"1")a`.

Answer (score 7):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), <s>159</s> 154 bytes

```r
function(n,H,s,`?`=paste0,`*`=strrep,`/`=Reduce,`+`=nchar,S=0*n?s?0*-(+s%%-n)?"?"/n%/%2^(n:1-1)%%2)(function(x,y)H(x?y))/substring(S,s<-seq(,+S,n),s--n-1)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jY/RSsNAEEXf@xUhENhJZ0laCIh0CYJIfLJYn2Vj3MRAO4k7G2j783G12kpF6OvMvWfO2LEOFnKsB6pc25EgLJBR51r1JTuToo61Ymet6VEnWj2a16EyqKdaUfVWWlypNKac8zSWYspRJAnyMA8TipJo/izoeiZnEEVzEMcbW9xBIbb5DiDh4cXTW2rECnkh2bwLnK6QAFlK8tXxZu2MpdIZ9qLBEcJwUBHfnicQ4yclxS8/n8M5/J0ATO5ayy47g/7GzDD7Sd22Tev4oV7azh91/5Z6vxeDq6@euntyfgUHyqQWpDJkFXpCY8vNxqeD5bDfrw2HWAQqOP0JF6QPWpcnzx6A8QM)

Yuck! Answering [string](/questions/tagged/string) challenges in R is never pretty, but this is horrible. This is an instructive answer on how not to write "normal" R code...

*Thanks to [nwellnhof](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/9296/nwellnhof) for fixing a bug, at a cost of 0 bytes!*

*Thanks to [J.Doe](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/81549/j-doe) for swapping the operator aliasing to change the precedence, good for -4 bytes.*

The explanation below is for the previous version of the code, but the principles remain the same.

```r
function(n,H,s,               # harmless-looking function arguments with horrible default arguments 
                              # to prevent the use of {} and save two bytes
                              # then come the default arguments,
                              # replacing operators as aliases for commonly used functions:
 `+`=paste0,                  # paste0 with binary +
 `*`=strrep,                  # strrep for binary *
 `/`=Reduce,                  # Reduce with binary /
 `?`=nchar,                   # nchar with unary ?
 S=                           # final default argument S, the padded string:
  0*n+                        # rep 0 n times
  s+                          # the original string
  0*-((?s)%%-n)+              # 0 padding as a multiple of n
  "+"/n%/%2^(n:1-1)%%2)       # n as an n-bit number
                              # finally, the function body:
 (function(x,y)H(x+y)) /      # Reduce/Fold (/) by H operating on x + y
  substring(S,seq(1,?S,n),seq(n,?S,n))  # operating on the n-length substrings of S
```

Comment: I think `0*(n-(?s)%%n)` doesn't work if n divides s evenly. But `0*-((?s)%%-n)` should work.

Comment: @nwellnhof ah, of course, thank you, fixed.

Comment: Minor changes, [155 bytes](https://tio.run/##jY/RSsNAEEXf@xUhENhJZ0lSCIh0CYJIfbJYn2Vj3MRAO4k7G2j783G12kpF6OvMvWfO2LEO5nKsB6pc25EgXCCjLrTqS3YmRR1rxc5a06NOtHo0r0NlUE@1ouqttLhSaUwFF2ksxZSjSBIUYREmFCXR7FnQdSYziKIZiOONLe5gIbbFDiDh4cXTW2rECnku2byLDKcrJECWknx3vFk7Y6l0hr1pcKQwHFzEt@iJxPiJSfFL0OdwBn8nAJO71rLLz6C/MRnmP6nbtmkdP9RL2/mj7t9S7/dicPXVU3dPzq/gQJnUglSOrEJPaGy52fh0sBz2@7XhEBeBCk5/wgXpg9blybMHYPwA "R – Try It Online")

Comment: @J.Doe nice! I saved another byte since `seq` has `1` as its `from` argument by default.

Answer (score 3):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 251 bytes

```c
#define P sprintf(R,
b(_){_=_>1?10*b(_/2)+_%2:_;}f(H,n,x)void(*H)(char*);char*x;{char R[2*n+1],c[n+1],*X=x;P"%0*d",n,0);while(strlen(x)>n){strncpy(c,x,n);x+=n;strcat(R,c);H(R);}P"%s%s%0*d",R,x,n-strlen(x),0);H(R);P"%s%0*d",R,n,b(n));H(R);strcpy(X,R);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VZFfa4MwFMXf/RSho5CkKVO7MrZg99pH8WngRGyMVmhvS7SdrfjZXf50g5GHk5/35HhvIpa1ENP0VMqqAYli1J5VA12FE@btcE6GPMo3wUfgU03PIVnk8/A952OFtwxYT66npsR0S7DYF4oSbqXng1GUpCGFRZAxkVqhn1HP49ncp@VMn/YJ/943B4nbTh0k4J5sgAwaQJxvWLCeAeH9IgKuv4mi0z0Jwrc4IXzUKa1eNikxzuVfiMm1Jut5OIDtMJBHwcTpP3wykzSZEZC8SnULoXRzaINtJPWzyEiQcSeWVo5CR2tHK0evjl4cvTlaZ5HPR0/fKzoWDWCzKVQtGLLXRPX@mmYEDR5CFf5thaE1Q7YUZITr0uNl9FRfMPtfUrK7KEA@98ZpitWpVsXx2ECN4sv9fpDtDw)

Not as clean as the bash solution, and highly improvable.

The function is `f` taking `H` as a function that replaces its string input with that string's hash, `n` as in the description, and `x` the input string and output buffer.

Description:

```c
#define P sprintf(R,     // Replace P with sprintf(R, leading to unbalanced parenthesis
                         // This is replaced and expanded for the rest of the description
b(_){                    // Define b(x). It will return the integer binary expansion of _
                         // e.g. 5 -> 101 (still as integer)
  _=_>1?                 // If _ is greater than 1
    10*b(_/2)+_%2        // return 10*binary expansion of _/2 + last binary digit
    :_;}                 // otherwise just _
f(H,n,x)                 // Define f(H,n,x)
  void(*H)(char*);       // H is a function taking a string
  char*x; {              // x is a string
  char R[2*n+1],c[n+1],  // Declare R as a 2n-length string and c as a n-length string
  *X=x;                  // save x so we can overwrite it later
  sprintf(R,"%0*d",n,0); // print 'n' 0's into R
  while(strlen(x)>n){    // while x has at least n characters
    strncpy(c,x,n);x+=n; // 'move' the first n characters of x into c
    strcat(R,c);         // concatenate c and R
    H(R);}               // Hash R
  sprintf(R,"%s%s%0*d"   // set R to two strings concatenated followed by some zeroes
    R,x,                 // the two strings being R and (what's left of) x
    n-strlen(x),0);      // and n-len(x) zeroes
  H(R);                  // Hash R
  sprintf(R,"%s%*d",R,n, // append to R the decimal number, 0 padded to width n
    b(n));               // The binary expansion of n as a decimal number
  H(R);strcpy(X,R);}     // Hash R and copy it into where x used to be
```

Comment: [229 bytes](https://tio.run/##VZFfa4MwEMDf/RSho5CzKVO3MrZg99pH8anQidgYndBeS7TFVvzs7jTdYAQu97v/uahlqdQwPOW6qFCziNVnU2FT8Fg4e55Cl4bp2v/0PZfoOYBFOg8@UtkXnKK4uwEOgjSGQn1nxm2hI3K3YSviHSZCkZDFyfBoNvfcfCZQeCDrxhw08hbWKNtFiLDhZFJZQ11JQXW@cSVagQAgKbOmM2XHo3H5lz7W2vD4EfOIQLHnlGgdY1kqthWk98P1VOVMX7W5BZjzaWAKgI7EzkvC8fITaa@JXiwFllaWXiy9WXq19G5plYSe7J1xI8eswnFJLDOlEmzsxlzSr7sEWOcwVvDfUQRbCTa5/AQkuR5/QK/6wtl/l9HNxSDzpNMPQ2ROpcmOxwpLFl3u94OufwA "C (gcc) – Try It Online")

Comment: I think: [227 bytes](https://tio.run/##VZFda4MwFIbv/RWHjkJiU2btZGzB7baX4lWhE7ExOqE9LdEWW/G3u6PpBiNw8j45n0nUslRqGJ5yXVSoIYL6bCpsChYLZ89S3qVh@rnyXNLPPl@kc/89lX3BKIa5G864IAUo1Hdm3JZ3RO42bEW8w0QoMrI4GRbN5p6bzwQKj8u6MQeNrOUfKNtFiHzD6EhlDfUkgep8Y0q0AjnnkjJrWlN2PB4u/9LHWhsWP2IeESj2jBKtYyxLxbaCdD9cT1UO@qrNzcecTQNTAO/I7LwkHLdVIu020dqSbymwtLb0aunF0pulIAk92TvjixyzCsdHgsyUSsDYDVzS113CoXMACvY7ioBAwORaJVyS6/EDdKsvnP13Gd1cDIInnX4YInMqTXY8VlhCdLnfD7r@AQ) (going off of ceilingcat's comment)

Answer (score 3):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 78 bytes

```ruby
->n,s,g{(([?0*n]*2*s).chop.scan(/.{#{n}}/)+["%0#{n}b"%n]).reduce{|s,x|g[s+x]}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FcbBCoMgGADg@54iGpGVWW3E2KH2Ct3FQ7lyg2XhP6FlPrvDy8en9PBzU@PyVmLAwiBEH2UqWXpJISH8tawEeC9RQczZSGuLJKNhVPoPYSRZQtT41Hw0B@DtEBSyjVnrRJO3YIBWLAN69dSem@fO7GnVXwgmWuO4U4tQ/Ty/pQg6ve@fEWIsmPsD)

#### How it works:

```ruby
([?0*n]*2*s).chop    # Padding: add leading and trailing 
                     # zeros, then remove the last one
.scan(/.{#{n}}/)     # Split the string into chunks
                     # of length n
+["%0#{n}b"%n]       # Add the trailing block
.reduce{|s,x|g[s+x]} # Apply the hashing function
                     # repeatedly
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 23 bytes

```
0Ṿ;s;BṾ€ṚWƲ}z”0ZU0¦;Ç¥/
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XZHNbtNAFIX38xSHFSChkLbKJlk58bixSMaWPRYqiIXlTJNBjqeaGVMlElLFBolHQO0KwYoVG9INSAXxHs6LmCGFVGIxP/feued@R/NSlOWqbTbvloek2XzokShurr/tbkc/v6PZfN1eXBIyjfwwOAEfhylYNh3SBA9c/SGsQm0EVOXWKexCuOBMu93itK4KK1Vl@uSgD/pK6BWMKFQ1Q7HIdV5YoclhH4HUxqJ3lzTk6C47k3NpzV9xJ61mdWH/hfsWFGomDJ77NPCyCX9ByImqUeQV8tIo@HRCOb3Fp4yHCcWYer5zkTsaLc7KvBCQFufSLrBStYY6r/YOOn/U9D7ENEs5uPeEwmM@EsqzhMFDypOQHT@C7IgOcpTS7EDjlV24JmO1rOY7J6Wo5m7OwX@6941DMXVpbwcMHaQ3CRw1xYSyYz5GFCDkKUIWZ7xDvNEoyhhHECWI3KsEQcZGPIxYeo@Q7cVV23V/OTCDoTu2bz431@@f/vryeu0q3WdZ9@bT4Mfbm4@P27aNtZrrfLl0gIjr9boUpu39Bg)

Accepts \$\mathcal H\$ at the line above it, \$s\$ as its left argument, and \$n\$ as its right argument.

Answer (score 2):

## [Bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/), 127-ε bytes

```bash
Z=`printf %0*d $1` R=$Z
while IFS= read -rn$1 c;do R=$R$c$Z;R=`H<<<${R::2*$1}`;done
H< <(printf $R%0*d $1 `bc <<<"obase=2;$1"`)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LYxPC4IwGIfvfooXe0MN0hZ0ye0adpN1Ew@bulQwja0IlD77MvH28PvzFNI0NvEDmBwAoyrwTBTmfpgHUU6i2pvTTaNkBfvy9OeXbLuFvzZj4qnb/nWH7WFXARIBnGHmfJq2U3C93Bjo5al7JFDG1fDvOZaYxZyJhFKKEz@fjzskXzHXvXISCtRfrchXL4iihHntDoU0ih1jJK4IrE31UGv5eLR9Del7HDtlHHv6AQ)

This works as a program/function/script/snippet. H must be resolveable to a program or function that will perform the hashing. N is the argument. Example call:

```bash
$ H() {
>   sed 's/.\(.\)/\1/g'
> }
$ ./wherever_you_put_the_script.sh 5 <<< "Programming Puzzles"  # if you add a shebang
Pe011
```

Description:

```bash
Z=`printf %0*d $1`
```

This creates a string of `$1` zeroes. This works by calling printf and telling it to print an integer padded to ***extra argument*** width. That extra argument we pass is `$1`, the argument to the program/function/script which stores n.

```bash
R=$Z
```

This merely copies Z, our zero string, to R, our result string, in preparation for the hashing loop.

```bash
while IFS= read -rn$1 c; do
```

This loops over the input every `$1` (n) characters loading the read characters into c. If the input ends then c merely ends up too short. The `r` option ensures that any special characters in the input don't get bash-interpreted. This is the `-ε` in the title - that `r` isn't strictly necessary, but makes the function more accurately match the input.

```bash
R=$R$c$Z
```

This concatenates the n characters read from input to R along with zeroes for padding (too many zeroes for now).

```bash
R=`H<<<${R::2*$1}`;done
```

This uses a here string as input to the hash function. The contents `${R::2*$1}` are a somewhat esoteric bash parameter substitution which reads: R, starting from 0, only 2n characters.

Here the loop ends and we finish with:

```bash
H< <(printf $R%0*d $1 `bc <<<"obase=2;$1"`)
```

Here the same format string trick is used to 0 pad the number. `bc` is used to convert it to binary by setting the output base (obase) to 2. The result is passed to the hash function/program whose output is not captured and thus is shown to the user.

Comment: Why "127-ε"? Why not just "127"?

Comment: I don't know. I was on the fence about the necessity of the `r` flag. I figured 1 byte doesn't really matter, but if pushed I could shave it.

Comment: For the `read` command?

Comment: Because without it a `\` in the input will be interpreted instead of ignored, so they'd have to be escaped.

Comment: Maybe add a note about that?

Comment: I did, in the description for the read command.

Comment: It's just not obvious from the title or first few lines.

Answer (score 2):

## [Perl 6](https://github.com/nxadm/rakudo-pkg), <s>79</s> 68 bytes

```perl6
{reduce &^h o&[~],comb 0 x$^n~$^s~$n.fmt("%.{$n-$s.comb%-$n}b"): $n}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HcrdCoIwGIDhW/kYUzTmRxF1UHQPnosDtc0Ut8WWkA536@vn6D143qew0zmqBVIJt@ituM@dgJQ/wKRVqFlnVAt7eFOuA@UuUI1SvTKSoKe6oA5/Q1JQvbUkv8C30TULyMz/pTqwIyLuahzNoDcGJwaktKa3jVKD7qGc13USjuTX@AE)

#### Explanation

```perl6
{
  reduce         # Reduce with
    &^h o&[~],   # composition of string concat and hash function
    comb         # Split string
      0 x$^n     # Zero repeated n times
      ~$^s       # Append input string s
      ~$n.fmt("  # Append n formatted
        %.       # with leading zeroes,
        {$n             # field width n for final chunk
         -$s.comb%-$n}  # -(len(s)%-n) for padding,
        b")      # as binary number
      :          # Method call with colon syntax
      $n         # Split into substrings of length n
}
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), 24 bytes

Since Pyth doesn't allow H to be used for a function name, I use `y` instead.

```
uy+GH+c.[E=`ZQQ.[ZQ.BQ*Z
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsyfjvo2pUkvS/tFLb3UM7WS/a1TYhKjBQLzoqUM8pUCvq/39TLqWAovz0osTc3My8dIWA0qqqnNRiJQA) Example is with the "every second character" version of H.

Answer (score 1):

## [GolfScript](http://www.golfscript.com/golfscript/), 47 bytes

```
~:π'0'*:s\+s+π/);[sπ2base{48+}%+0π->]+{+1$~}*\;
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8/PSStOLsosKPmfp1r9v87qfIO6gbqWVXGMdrH2@QZ9Tevo4vMNRkmJxanVJhbataraBucbdO1itau1DVXqarVirP/XquZp/a82tDNSrVVQDyjKTy9KzM3NzEtXCCitqspJLVZXMOWqNrXBJ2mHR7Jaq1YrAZ92AA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Clean](https://github.com/Ourous/curated-clean-linux), 143 bytes

```
import StdEnv
r=['0':r]
$n h s=foldl(\a b=h(a++b))(r%(1,n))([(s++r)%(i,i+n-1)\\i<-[0,n..length s]]++[['0'+toChar((n>>(n-p))rem 2)\\p<-[1..n]]])
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JY7NSgMxFEb3fYq7aJ2EzIRWcCOdbtSFIDjQZZJFOr@B5GZIUsHisxuj7s63OIevt6PG7PxwtSM4bTAbt/qQ4JyGF/zYhFZU@@oxqM0WYYHYTt4OlkgNl3YhmrELpSTsyKHGAoJExgLdEVMbhs2BSmmOjdjXyLkdcU6loBRj4jfKkn9adCAETyeCzUppGB3cF2ctzoFzVErRfE663GlhCw9AZCwkein7YxPv/tqcqy8T34cBjKIgqi74OWjnDM7QXW83O8ZK5e9@snqOuXl9y8@fqJ3p/0dndZp8cD8)

Answer (score 1):

## [oK](https://github.com/JohnEarnest/ok), 41 bytes

```
{(x#48)(y@,)/(0N,x)#z,,/$((x+x!-#z)#2)\x}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y9bNz/7/P82qWqNC2cRCU6PSQUdTX8PAT6dCU7lKR0dfRUOjQrtCUVe5SlPZSDOmovZ/mp66hoapdXWFg5qRoqJyRa21UkBRfnpRYm5uZl66QkBpVVVOarGSJhdIkamyipY@TiWa/wE)

```
{                                       } /x is n, y is H, z is s.
                          (x+x!-#z)       /number of padding 0's needed + x
                         (         #2)\x  /binary(x) with this length
                      ,/$                 /to string
                    z,                    /append to z
             (0N,x)#                      /split into groups of length x
       (y@,)/                             /foldl of y(concat(left, right))...
 (x#48)                                   /...with "0"*x as the first left string
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>126</s> 113 bytes

```python
lambda n,H,s:reduce(lambda x,y:H(x+y),re.findall('.'*n,'0'*n+s+'0'*(n-len(s)%n))+[bin(n)[2:].zfill(n)])
import re
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XY6xCoMwFEV3vyJLSV6TSit0CXR3dLcOaU1sIHmGGEH9@dRCu3Q5Bw5cuGFNrxGrbG737JR/9IqgqMUko@7np2bftohV1mzhK4ioS2OxV84xWtIjCnreySf@McOT08gmOCAAbx8WGUJbya7cjN0XCB0U1ocxJhJ1DtFiIoZZDHNiIP4M@Vr8DsilvUhZdQVt4jhE5b3FgTTzttE3)

-13 thanks to [Triggernometry](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/73368/triggernometry).

Yeah, this is an abomination, why can't I just use a built-in to split a string into chunks...? :-(

Comment: https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/173952/55696 A `while` loop is the best builtin I could hope for. 104 bytes

Comment: @StevenH. Yeah, especially if you're actually focusing on the golfing itself. >_>

Comment: `'0'*~-n` instead of `'0'*(len(s)%n)` is shorter (and actually correct for shorter inputs).

Comment: @nwellnhof Yeah, but it's definitely not the same thing.

Comment: Maybe I wasn't clear enough. Your solution gives the wrong answer for strings like `Programming Puzz` (16 chars). Replacing `'0'*(len(s)%n)` with `'0'*~-n` fixes that and saves 7 bytes.

Comment: @nwellnhof Ah, yep, applied a little patch over there, I'll have to test your suggestion a bit though.

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>106</s> 102 bytes

For once, the function outgolfs the lambda. -4 bytes for simple syntax manipulation, thanks to Jo King.

```python
def f(n,H,s):
 x='0'*n;s+='0'*(n-len(s)%n)+bin(n)[2:].zfill(n)
 while s:x=H(x+s[:n]);s=s[n:]
 return x
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XY2xDoMgFAB3vuItDVBt05p0ecbd0d0waEQlwacBTKk/T03HTnc33fYJ80pFSoMeYRSU17mXyCBW/MGvVPrsJ4JuVpPw8kIy6w0Jkm2B6n6MxtozGLxnYzV4jFUtYuZbJCVLX/mWUDFwOuyOIKbNGQrnyNC2ByHzP8r0YrZb@qGDiLF9IhaK8catk@uWxdAEzX4cVnv@BQ)

Comment: Shouldn't the result be 'Pe011', not 'e011'?

Comment: That it should. Fixed!

Comment: Use semi-colons instead of newlines. [-4 bytes](https://tio.run/##XY2xDoMgFAB3vuItDVBt05p0ecbd0d0waEQlwacBTKk/T03HTnc33fYJ80pFSoMeYRSU17mXyCBW/MGvVPrsJ4JuVpPw8kIy6w0Jkm2B6n6MxtozGLxnYzV4jFUtYuZbJCVLX/mWUDFwOuyOIKbNGQrnyNC2ByHzP8r0YrZb@qGDiLF9IhaK8catk@uWxdAEzX4cVnv@BQ "Python 2 – Try It Online")

Comment: I didn't realize that worked for while loops as well, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 27 bytes

```
òV ú'0 pV¤ùTV)rÈ+Y gOvW}VçT
```

[Try it!](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.6&code=8lYg+icwIHBWpPlUVilyyCtZIGdPdld9VudU&input=IlByb2dyYW1taW5nIFB1enpsZXMiCjUKIl/rMiwxIgotUQ==)

I haven't found any capability for Japt to take functions directly as an input, so this takes a string which is interpreted as Japt code and expects it to define a function. Specifically, `OvW` takes the third input and interprets it as Japt, then `g` calls it. Replacing that with `OxW` allows input as a Javascript function instead, or if the function were (somehow) already stored in W it could just be `W` and save 2 bytes. The link above has the worked example of \$\mathcal{H}\$ that takes characters at odd indexes, while [this one](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.6&code=8lYg+icwIHBWpPlUVilyyCtZIGdPdld9VudU&input=IlByb2dyYW1taW5nIFB1enpsZXMiCjUKIl9xIG1jINdzIHMwLDUiCi1R) is the "multiply char-codes and take the 5 highest digits" example.

Due to the way Japt takes inputs, \$s\$ will be `U`, \$n\$ will be `V`, and \$\mathcal{H}\$ will be `W`

Explanation:

```
òV                             Split U into segments of length V
   ú'0                         Right-pad the short segment with "0" to the same length as the others
       p     )                 Add an extra element:
        V¤                       V as a base-2 string
          ùTV                    Left-pad with "0" until it is V digits long
              r                Reduce...
                        VçT          ...Starting with "0" repeated V times...
               È       }                                                  ...By applying:
                +Y               Combine with the previous result
                   gOvW          And run W as Japt code
```